# Example of a semisimple Lie algebra with degenerate Killing form

Tags: lie-algebras

We know that when the killing form of a Lie algebra is nondegenerate then it is semisimple. I am looking for a semisimple Lie algebra with degenerate killing form. I know if the field is of characteristic zero it is impossible to find one.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_criterion#Examples has 3 examples

Comment: @rVitale thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the exercises of Humphreys book on Lie algebras and Representation theory the example of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ (respectively of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)/Z(\mathfrak{sl}(3))$ in characteristic $3$ is worked out. Its Killing form is identical zero, but $\mathfrak{sl}(3)/Z(\mathfrak{sl}(3))$ is still a simple Lie algebra in characteristic $3$.
One can find all details in the solutions [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi4ju6w4q7sAhUWilwKHVLRCWkQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.warwick.ac.uk%2F%7Emasdf%2Fmodular%2Fln_11mar.pdf&usg=AOvVaw325kOvRTPAZ-OQuAm8n-8X). The matrix of the Killing form relative to the standard basis is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
12 & -6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
-6 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is identical zero for $3=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but sorry you link seems to be redirecting me to an error page. Would it be possible to upload an alternative one?

Comment: @asrxiiviii Thank you for telling me about the link. I have updated the link. Searching "classical modular Lie algebra psl(n)" I obtain many other references. You can try these links by searching yourself . Then you are independent of outdated links.